# How to make sigmoid function at Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I'm trying to make something like this at Tikz:

The function is:
y=1/(1+e^(-x))

[image]

but I don't know how to do it because the axis are at different scales.
Can you help me with it?

Thank you!

P.S. I'd like to add the axis with the numbers and help grids (if it's possible).

[Source of the graph](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html)

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `pgfplots` package.

Comment: What is the function of your curve?

Comment: @luki - I? add the function. Thank you!

Comment: @luki - I know this package but it's little bit complicated so I'd like to get help...

Comment: mwe next time pls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of your function using the `pgfplots` package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = {sigmoid function},
        axis on top = true,
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        grid = major,
        xlabel = $Z$
    ]
        \addplot[
            blue,
            domain = -5:5,
            samples = 100
        ]
            {1/(1+exp(-x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot1]

The axis settings (range, grid, appearance, ..) can be defined in the optional argument of the `axis` environment. Inside the `axis` environment you can plot multiple curves or data point series using `\addplot` macros.

## Edit

Here's a version using `pgfplots` which looks more similar to your example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height = 7.3cm,
        width = 11cm,
        title = {sigmoid function},
        axis on top = true,
        axis x line = bottom,
        axis y line = left,
        x axis line style = -,
        y axis line style = -,
        tick align = outside,
        every tick/.append style = {
            black,
            thin
        },
%       grid = major,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 1,
        xlabel = $Z$
    ]
        \addplot[
            blue,
            domain = -5:5,
            samples = 100
        ]
            {1/(1+exp(-x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: plot2]

Answer (score 3):

I found something that show this function:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [scientific axes, visualize as smooth line,x axis={length=7cm}, y axis = {length=5cm},all axes = grid] 
    data[format=function] { 
    var x : interval [-4:4]; 
    func y = 1/(1+exp(-1*(\value x))); 
    };   
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

And I saw it at [Tikz manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (page 758): `74 Introduction to Data Visualization`

Answer (score 2):

I often use classical style, by hand ^^

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=3,nodes={scale=.8}]
\draw[gray] (-3.2,1)--(3.2,1);
\draw[->] (0,-.1)--(0,1.2) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[->] (-3.2,0)--(3.2,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[smooth,thick,cyan] plot[domain=-3:3] (\x,{1/(1+exp{-\x})});
\path
(0,0) node[below left]{O}
(0,.5) node[above left]{$0.5$}
(0,1) node[above right]{$1$}
(-2,.75) node[align=center,teal]
{the sigmoid function\\
$y=\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$};
\foreach \i in {-2,2}
\draw (\i,.02)--(\i,-.02) node[below]{$\i$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: as OP asked.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=5]
\draw (-5,1)|-(5,0);
\draw[smooth,thick,magenta] plot[domain=-5:5] (\x,{1/(1+exp{-\x})});
\path (current bounding box.north) 
node[above,magenta]{the sigmoid function}
(current bounding box.south) node[below=8mm]{Z};
\foreach \i in {-5,...,5}
\draw (\i,0)--+(-90:.04) node[below]{$\i$};
\foreach \j in {0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0}
\draw (-5,\j)--+(180:.15) node[left]{$\j$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very clear the graph and the code.

Comment: @Sebastiano: thank you!

Comment: Thank you! But can you make it like the picture I posted above? (because your axis are different). Thanks!

Comment: @heblyx Of courrse I can do that for you. (even I am not sure the figure you posted is the good one) Please wait until I have free time!

Comment: @heblyx I added more code!